# What does $ mean/do in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, operators, dollar-sign

When you are writing slightly more complex functions I notice that `$` is used a lot but I don't have a clue what it does?

Comment: It's the "apply" operator. This blog does an alright job getting the basic of it covered: http://snakelemma.blogspot.com/2009/12/dollar-operator-in-haskell.html

Answer (score 80):

`$` is infix "application". It's defined as

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x = f x

-- or 
($) f x = f x
-- or
($) = id
```

It's useful for avoiding extra parentheses: `f (g x) == f $ g x`.

A particularly useful location for it is for a "trailing lambda body" like

```
forM_ [1..10] $ \i -> do
  l <- readLine
  replicateM_ i $ print l
```

compared to

```
forM_ [1..10] (\i -> do
  l <- readLine
  replicateM_ i (print l)
)
```

Or, trickily, it shows up sectioned sometimes when expressing "apply this argument to whatever function"

```
applyArg :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
applyArg x = ($ x)

>>> map ($ 10) [(+1), (+2), (+3)]
[11, 12, 13]
```

Comment: Yep. It's also written `f . g . h $ x` sometimes, which could also be `(f . g . h) x`.

Comment: Technical note: AFAIK, the definition of `$` is a bit of a lie at present.  GHC actually treats it as syntax so that the `runST $ do` idiom works (except in things like sections where it really is a function).  It should be just a function, but higher rank types are a problem.

Comment: Agreed—[source from Simon Peyton Jones here](http://www.mail-archive.com/glasgow-haskell-users@haskell.org/msg18923.html)

Comment: `<$>` is just infix `fmap`. It doesn't do anything special as far as I know.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out, along with the operators's signature, that its PRECEDENCE is 0.  So, everything binds more tightly than $.

Comment: What if I write (10 $) in your last example. It doesn't produce any output.

Comment: @johnbakers `(a->b)->a->b` is same as `(a->b)->(a->b)` because `->` is right associative.

Answer (score 31):

I like to think of the $ sign as a replacement for parenthesis.

For example, the following expression:

```
take 1 $ filter even [1..10] 
-- = [2]
```

What happens if we don't put the $? Then we would get

```
take 1 filter even [1..10]
```

and the compiler would now complain, because it would think we're trying to apply 4 arguments to the `take` function, with the arguments being `1 :: Int`, `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`, `even :: Integral a => a -> Bool`, `[1..10] :: [Int]`.

This is obviously incorrect. So what can we do instead? Well, we could put parenthesis around our expression:

`(take 1) (filter even [1..10])`

This would now reduce to:

`(take 1) ([2,4,6,8,10])`

which then becomes:

`take 1 [2,4,6,8,10]`

But we don't always want to be writing parenthesis, especially when functions start getting nested in each other. An alternative is to place the `$` sign between where the pair of parenthesis would go, which in this case would be:

`take 1 $ filter even [1..10]`

Comment: how does the compiler infer where the end of the parentheses goes?

Comment: When it finds the next `$` symbol otherwise the end of the line.