# How to understand this `$` usage in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, operators, dollar-sign, operator-sections

This happens in the situation you want to apply bunch of functions to the same variable, it may look like this:

```
map (\f->f 4) [odd, even]
```

but from [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) using `$` make it very neat

```
map ($ 4) [odd, even]
```

why does it work. first I type it in ghci like `$ 4 odd`, it failed, then I type `($ 4) odd`, which works fine. then I check the type of `($ 4)` using `:t` which shows `($ 4) :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b`, `odd` is `odd :: Integral a => a -> Bool`. It seems make sense, but still not clear to me.

Can anyone explain it clearly, is it another common usage of `$`, and is there other more usage of `$`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521246/what-does-mean-do-in-haskell

Comment: Basically, it's the same as `(+ 5)` or `(* 3)`.

Answer (score 7):

### Anatomy of the operator

The `$` application operator is in the form:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

It's often seen in situation when you want to avoid a trailing pair of parenthesis:

```
func a (b + c)
```

is equal to:

```
func a $ b + c
```

The magic behind this is simply explained in its [fixity declaration](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords#infixr):

```
infixr 0
```

This means: everything that is after `$` will be grouped into a single entity, just like if they where enclosed in parenthesis.

Of course this can be also "nested" like so:

```
func a $ b + other $ c - d
```

which means:

```
func a (b + other (c - d))
```

### Application operator as function

Your case is very interesting and, in my experience, not used very often.

Let's analyze this:

```
map ($ 4) [odd, even]
```

We know that `map`'s type is:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

The behavior, if someone forgot, is: take the first argument (a function from `a` to `b`) and apply it to every `a` in the second argument list, finally return the resulting list.

You can see `($ 4)` as "pass 4 as argument to something". Which means that:

```
($ 4) func
```

is the same as:

```
func $ 4
```

So:

```
map ($ 4) [odd, even]
```

means:

```
[($ 4) odd, ($ 4) even]
[(odd $ 4), (even $ 4)]
[False, True]
```

### Why (func $) is not necessary

You could argue that, just like you can do `(/ 4)` and `(2 /)` which respectively means "divide something by 4" and "divide 2 by something", you could do `($ 4)` and `(func $)` and you would be right.

In fact:

```
(func $) 4
```

is the same as:

```
func $ 4
func 4
```

which is the same as:

```
($ 4) func
```

But the reality is that:

```
map (func $) [...]
```

would be unnecessary, since the first argument of `map` is always applied to each argument to the list, making the above the same as:

```
map func [...]
```

Comment: I think you mean "apply something to 4".

Answer (score 3):

1. `$ 4 odd`: This won't work because operators must be surrounded by parentheses when not used in infix form.  If you were to do `($) 4 odd`, this wouldn't work because argument order is incorrect, you want `4` to be the second argument.  You could write `($) odd 4` though.
2. `($ 4) odd`: This does work because it's using *operator sections*, and here the `4` is provided as the second argument to `$`.  It's like `(++ "world") "hello "` being the same as `"hello " ++ "world"`.
3. When you have `($ 4) :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b`, and `odd :: Integral a => a -> Bool`, you just need to line up the types.  Since every `Integral a` is also a `Num a`, we can just "upgrade" (constrain) the `Num` to `Integral` for this to work:

```hs
($ 4) :: Integral a => (a ->    b) -> b
odd   :: Integral a =>  a -> Bool
```

So `a ~ a` and `b ~ Bool`, so you can say that

```
($ 4) :: Integral a => (a -> Bool) -> Bool
```

So applying it to `odd` gives us

```
($ 4) odd :: Bool
```

This is because `($ 4) odd` is the same as `odd $ 4`.  Looking at the definition of `$`:

```
f $ x = f x
```

We can say that

```
odd $ 4 = odd 4
```

Which evaluates to `False`.

Comment: It might be better to illustrate the (+ 1) 2 comparison in #2 with an operator that isn't commutative, since part of the OP's confusion is around which argument is first.

Comment: thanks very much! I haven't noticed `$` is infix operator, treated it like `++` make it clear to me. so `($)` becomes prefix, then `($) f x` = `f $ x` = `(f $) x` = `($ x) f`.

Comment: @delta Precisely, `$` is an operator just like any other in Haskell.  Just like `+`, `*`, `++`, `<>`, `<`, `==`, `.`, and many, many others.  That's one thing that I really like about the language, there aren't very many special cases with its syntax.  Much of it can be passed around just like user-defined operators and functions.

Answer (score 3):

Infix operators like `*`, `++`, or `$` typically take two arguments as in

```
x ++ y
```

When one argument is missing, and they are put  between parentheses, they instead form a *section*:

```
(x ++)
(++ y)
```

These sections are equivalent to, respectively,

```
\y -> x ++ y
\x -> x ++ y
```

i.e., they stand for the function that maps the "missing argument" to the result. For instance,

```
map ("A"++) ["a","b"] == [ "Aa","Ab" ]
map (++"A") ["a","b"] == [ "aA","bA" ]
```

Operator `$` is not special in this respect. We have

```
(f $)
($ x)
```

which stands for

```
\x -> f $ x
\f -> f $ x
```

The first is not very useful, since `(f $)` is `\x -> f $ x` which is (eta-)equivalent to just `f` (*). The second is instead useful.

(*) To be picky, `seq` can distinguish between `undefined` and `(undefined $)`, but this is a minor difference in practice.