# Function elem is throwing errors

Tags: haskell

My Haskell code is as follows

```
isNotPrime x = elem 0 map (mod x)[3.. (x-1)]
```

When compiled it shows these errors

```
  Couldn't match expected type ‘(t1 -> t1) -> [t1] -> t’
              with actual type ‘Bool’
  The function ‘elem’ is applied to four arguments,
  but its type ‘([a0] -> [b0])
                -> ((a0 -> b0) -> [a0] -> [b0]) -> Bool’
  has only two
  In the expression: elem 0 map (mod x) [3 .. (x - 1)]
  In an equation for ‘prime’:
      prime x = elem 0 map (mod x) [3 .. (x - 1)]
```

My understanding is that elem accepts two arguments, I do not understand how am I passing 4 arguments in the above code as the map function should just return a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *are* passing four arguments to the `elem` function. Function application always associates left, so the expression

```
f a b c d
```

is parsed like this:

```
((((f a) b) c) d)
```

Therefore, your example is getting parsed like this:

```
((((elem 0) map) (mod x)) [3.. (x-1)])
```

That is, `elem` is being “applied to four arguments”, but of course all Haskell functions are actually just functions of one argument, just curried. What you *actually* want is a different grouping, so you just need to add some parentheses:

```
elem 0 (map (mod x) [3.. (x-1)])
```

Alternatively, you could [use `$` to avoid writing the parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521246/what-does-mean-do-in-haskell):

```
elem 0 $ map (mod x) [3.. (x-1)]
```

Or you could write `elem` infix, which is a common idiom in Haskell. Like `$`, this will also change the precedence to be what you want:

```
0 `elem` map (mod x) [3.. (x-1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The four arguments you are passing are `0`, `map`, `mod x` and `[3.. (x-1)]`. You intended to pass `mod x` and `[3.. (x-1)]` as arguments to `map` and then pass the result as the second argument to `elem`, but there's no way for Haskell to know that without parentheses or `$`. So to make your code work add them:

```
isNotPrime x = elem 0 (map (mod x) [3.. (x-1)])
-- or
isNotPrime x = elem 0 $ map (mod x) [3.. (x-1)]
```

Or you can use infix notation, in which case precedence rules (prefix function application binds tighter than any infix operator) removes the need for parentheses:

```
isNotPrime x = 0 `elem` map (mod x) [3.. (x-1)]
```