# Definition of Haskell's $-Operator

Tags: haskell, definition

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521246/what-does-mean-do-in-haskell) and other sources like [this](http://lambda.jstolarek.com/2012/03/function-composition-and-dollar-operator-in-haskell/) insist that the definition of the $-operator is

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x = f x
```

or

```
($) f x = f x
```

or

```
($) = id
```

but I didn't understand why this definition would be able to replace parentheses, so I tried to reproduce that myself and examine the behaviour, by defining:

```
k :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
k f x = f x
```

But what I got is:

```
-- these work:
(+2) `k` 4
(+2) `id` 4
sum `k` [1,2]
sum `id` [1,2]
map (flip(-)3) $ filter even `k`  filter (>=0) [-5..10]
map (flip(-)3) $ filter even `id` filter (>=0) [-5..10]

-- these don't:
sum `k`  1:[2]
sum `id` 1:[2]
map (flip(-)3) `id` filter even $ filter (>=0) [-5..10]
```

Shouldn't `k` be a replacement for `$`? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing the [fixity declaration](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#%24):

```
infixr 0 $
```

Or in your example:

```
infixr 0 `k`
```

Fixity declarations tell the parser what the precedence/associativity of an infix operator is.