# create function that implements an array in haskell

Tags: python

I need to implement  the function is called rufit

Comment: This is not an array but a list. Can you make a fair attempt? Hint: take a look at the number of zeros in between.

Comment: You've replaced the old question with a new one. The problem with this is that the answers no longer match the question. I suggest reverting your edit, and then starting a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The identity of a number *n* is a sequence that starts with `1` followed by *n-1* sequences of *n* zeros and one one. So:

```
                         n-1 sequences of [0, 0, …, 1]
                   ____________________^_______________________
                  /                                            \
indentity n = [1, 0, 0, …, 0, 1, 0, 0, …, 0, 1, …, 0, 0, …, 0, 1]
                  \___ ____/
                      v
                   n times
```

We can make use of [**`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) to repeat an element a given number of times, for example:

```
Prelude> replicate 4 0
[0,0,0,0]
```

We thus can make a sequence of `n` zeros and one `1` with:

```
sequence :: Num a => Int -> [a]
sequence n = replicate n 0 ++ [1]
```

Then the identity function thus should use `sequence` as a subexpression. You can make use of [**`concat :: Foldable f => f [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat) to concatenate for example a list of lists to a list:

the identity function thus looks like:

```
identity :: Num a => Int -> [a]
identity n = 1 : …
```

where you still need to fill in `…`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to break the problem into smaller, easier problems.

Maybe start by making a single row, instead of the whole matrix.

To make a row, you need to know the row number and the length `n` of the row. So you could have a `makeRow` function:

```
makeRow :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
makeRow n rowNum =
    map (\x -> if x == rowNum then 1 else 0) [1..n]
```

So the position of the 1 in the row depends on the row number.

Now the `identity` function is easier. Make a list of rows and then flatten the list:

```
identity :: Int -> [Int]
identity n =
    mconcat $ map (makeRow n) [1..n]
```

Comment: ```mconcat (map (makeRow n) [1..n])```, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19521376/6629874

Answer (score 1):

First, notice an identity matrix is square, meaning it has n^2 elements, so we need to generate a list of n^2 values. Let's create a list with 1 at the beginning followed by n zeros. Start by replicating zero n times. We can do this with [`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate). Then use cons `(:)` to tack a 1 onto the start of the zeros.

```
1 : replicate n 0
```

We can use the [`cycle :: [a] -> [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:cycle) function on the above list to make it infinitely repeat. Due to laziness, it will only compute what is needed. All we really need from the infinite list is the first n^2 elements, so just [`take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take) the first n^2 elements.

```
identity n = take (n^2) $ cycle $ 1 : replicate n 0
```