# How to get a record field? Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, get, record

I have a **record** of **Person**

```
data Person = Person
 {name :: Name
 ,lastname :: LastName
 ,personId :: Int
 ,parentList :: [Int]
 ,childList :: [Int]
 ,siblingList ::[Int]
 }
 deriving (Show,Typeable,Data,Eq)
```

and **get function**

```
getPersonId::Person -> Int
getPersonId = personId --here why/how can I achieve to get personId field of Person record since I don't have any Person p
```

They work correctly and I get what I want **but** I struggle to understand these functions:

```
idGetters :: [Person->[Int]]
idGetters = [parentList]

ids :: Person -> [[Int]]
ids p = (fmap ($ p)) idGetters
```

I am studying for *functors* and *applicative* at the moment but I should be able to understand idGetters function(or whatever it is because by definition it is list of functions not a function itself)* with the help of what I know so far.
What I couldn't understand is :

1. I feel like I need to give a parameter to idGetters type but it doesn't need. **Why?** *How should I call this?*
2. *ids p = (fmap ($ p)) idGetters* in this line **how come can idGetters return** **p's** parentList which is [Int]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I feel like I need to give a parameter to idGetters type but it
> doesn't need. Why? How should I call this?

You can't call it, because it's not a function. Its type is `[Person->[Int]]` which is not a function but a *list* of functions.

In this case, because of its definition, it's in fact a list containing only one function - but you only know that from the implementation, not the type. If that's really the intended implementation then it would probably make more sense to just return that function not wrapped in a list, in which case the type would indeed be a function type `Person->[Int]`. However, based on the other fields in your record I assume the definition will at some point be extended to include the 3 relevant getter functions: `[parentList, childList, siblingList]`, and in this case you will of course need a list type.

> `ids p = (fmap ($ p)) idGetters` in this line how come can idGetters
> return p's parentList which is [Int]?

I'm not quite sure I understand exactly what you're asking, but I accept that the definition can look a little confusing, so I'll try to explain it.

Firstly, the type of `ids` is given as `Person -> [[Int]]`, so it's a function that takes a `Person` and returns a list of lists of `Int`s. From this we can tell that the `p` in the definition above - `ids p = ...` - must be a `Person`.

The result of that function call is the result of `fmap`-ing a function over `idGetters`. We'll worry about exactly what that function is shortly, but for now, just notice that `idGetters`, as discussed above, is a list of functions each of which is of type `Person -> [[Int]]`. So the function we `fmap` over that must take as its argument a *function*, and this function argument will take a `Person` as an argument and return a list of lists of `Int`s.

That function, in the definition we are given, is `($ p)`, which is a [section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) of the [$ operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521246/what-does-mean-do-in-haskell). That operator takes a function and a value and simply applies the function to the value, so when it's sectioned as `($ p)`, it's the function that takes another function and applies it to `p`.

(It may be clearer to write this out as follows:

```
($ p) = \f -> ($ p) f
      = \f -> f $ p
      = \f -> f p
```

)

This hopefully now all fits together nicely. In the context of a function from the list `idGetters` - which we know must be of type `Person -> [Int]` - `($ p)` must take a `Person` and apply that function to it, resulting in a list of `Int`s. So we we `fmap` that function over `idGetters`, we get a list of lists of `Int`s, which is what we know `ids` must return (from its type signature).

With the very simply definition of `idGetters` you have, consisting of the single function `parentList`, all this will do is, given a `Person`, output its `parentList` (which is of type `[Int]`) but wrapped inside another list (to have overall type `[[Int]]`). If, as I suggested earlier, `idGetters` was a list of the 3 relevant functions: `[parentList, childList, siblingList]`, then `ids` when applied to a `Person` would return a list of 3 sublists, which are respectively the `parentList`, `childList` and `siblingList` of that particular person. So it's actually a fairly straightforward function, just packaging up some of the information from a `Person`'s definition in some perhaps-relevant way.

I hope this clears up your questions - if not, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Many thanks Robin for the lambda expression for ($ p) I finally understand how it works. But also how could we express (fmap ($ p)) idGetters with function composition?

Comment: That expression is not a function (it's of type `[[Int]]`) so you can't express it as a function composition. Perhaps you mean `ids`, which is `\p -> (fmap ($ p)) idGetters` - in which case you can write it as a composition, eg `(flip $ idGetters) . fmap . (flip $)` (I think - I have haven't tested it). But there's no real gain to write every function definition in such a semi-cryptic way.

Comment: Too late to edit but that `flip $ idGetters` is totally wrong - I meant `flip ($) idGetters`, although really that's better expressed as a section `($ idGetters)`.