# Why does Haskell give me error when I try to implement "inserter" function to create a tree using a list as an input?

Tags: haskell

```
data Tree = EmptyTree | Node Integer Tree Tree deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

insertElement x EmptyTree = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree -- BASE CASE
insertElement x (Node a left right) = if x == a -- DO NOTHING
    then (Node x left right)
    else if x < a -- INSERT TO LEFT
    then (Node a (insertElement x left) right)
    else -- INSERT TO RIGHT
    Node a left (insertElement x right)

inserter (x:list) = insertElement x (insertElement (inserter (list)) (EmptyTree))
```

I have got the above Haskell Code. The `inserter` function is supposed to return a tree when we give a list to it. Everything other than `inserter` works perfectly fine. When I try to :r this file, it gives me the error

```
Couldn't match type `Tree' with `Integer'
    Expected type: [Integer] -> Integer
      Actual type: [Integer] -> Tree
```

What should I change about the `inserter` function?

Comment: Please add type signatures to clarify what you're trying to accomplish. (When doing this you might even find the error yourself!)

Comment: `inserter (list)` returns a tree and you're trying to pass the tree to `insertElement` as an element

Answer (score 2):

```hs
insertElement :: Integer -> Tree -> Tree
inserter :: [Integer] -> Tree
inserter (x:list) = insertElement x (insertElement (inserter (list)) (EmptyTree))
--                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
-- Assuming the signatures are as above, the problem is ^ here
```

Your `insertElement` expects an `Integer` as first argument but you provide a `Tree`

You can change the definition of `inserter` to the following:

```hs
insereter :: [Integer] -> Tree
inserter [] = EmptyTree
inserter (x:list) = insertElement x $ inserter list
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What does '$' mean in the code you wrote?

Comment: `$` is just [function application with a low precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521246/what-does-mean-do-in-haskell).

Comment: @malai_320 `insertElement x $ inserter list` simply means `insertElement x (inserter list)`